# How to get attribute codes used to build configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute

I need to get attribute codes used to build to the configurable product. How to get them in PHP? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributes($product);
```

You might want to add some checks, in case the product you are supplying isn't configurable.

`\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::getConfigurableAttributes` is only available there.

Comment: How can I get attribute code from returned value from getConfigurableAttributes?